# React.js: Unexpected template string expression no-template-curly-in-string

Tags: node.js, reactjs

```
handleNext = async () => {
    console.log("Next");
    let url =
      'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=in&apiKey=eae0696c32814d94af8f1f9c908cb49d?&page=${this.state.page + 1}';
    let data = await fetch(url);
    let parsedData = await data.json();

    this.setState({
      page: this.state.page + 1,
      articles: parsedData.articles,
    });
  };
```

**when i try to use ${this.state.page + 1} i got a error: Unexpected template string expression  no-template-curly-in-string and the url did not get the value of this prop**

Comment: Take a look at the [rule details](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-template-curly-in-string) and you should find your answer. (You should be using backticks (`\``) around your string, not quotes (`'`))

Answer (score 0):

As @George said, you must use backticks ` instead of quotes ' to interpolate the string.

```js
handleNext = async () => {
    console.log("Next");
    let url =
      `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=in&apiKey=eae0696c32814d94af8f1f9c908cb49d?&page=${this.state.page + 1}`;
    let data = await fetch(url);
    let parsedData = await data.json();

    this.setState({
      page: this.state.page + 1,
      articles: parsedData.articles,
    });
  };
```